# Why do I get "Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))" error when opening Monogame pipeline?

Tags: c#, pipeline, monogame

When I try to open MonoGame pipeline (MGCB Editor), I get an error that says either `"Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))"` or `"The Extender Provider failed to return an Extender for this object"`. The editor still opens, and I can add and build items there, but the error bothers me.

I tried to reinstall MonoGame, but it didn't help. It appeared out of nowhere and I have no clue why or how to fix it.

Comment: I am seeing this same error catastrophic error. When using Visual Studio 17.5.0, double-clicking on the MGCB Editor from VS worked correctly. After updating to Visual Studio 17.7.3, I am getting the Catastrophic Failure described above. However, after clicking OK from the catastrophic error modal dialog, the MonoGame Content Editor comes up and still works.

Answer (score 2):

Glad to see I'm not the only one who has this issue. I've just been opening MGCB from the taskbar. Not exactly a solution, but it avoids the error message.

Comment: What do you mean by "opening MGCB from the taskbar"? Could you elaborate?

Comment: It seems as a VS issue. I downgraded back to 16.5 version from 17.1 and it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Either upgrade to 17.8 (recommended) or downgrade to 17.6. It seems this is just an annoyance with 17.7 and a few other versions as noted.  While annoying, it doesn't seem to cause harm or prevent any functionality of the applications.